# How to program a atMega328p MCU with a Raspberry Pi 4 (Python)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, spi, raspberry-pi4, atmega32

I been looking everywhere online for this exact configuration but can't find much.

I want to program my AtMega328p MCU (its on a breadboard) using Python from my Raspberry Pi 4 but I am not sure how to check if communication is going on between them? I have the MISO, MOSI, SCLK, and CE0 pins from the Pi connected to the MISO, MOSI, SCK, SS pins on the AtMega328p respectively.

I understand I have to use SPI communication, however how can I exactly send data from the Raspberry Pi to the MCU to ensure there is communication between the two? Maybe some code to send to the MCU and receive it back? I been using the SPI Dev Python libraries but can't find much info on it. Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load code onto the AVR (program it), you want to use existing software like `avrdude` that already speaks the AVR ISP protocol. `avrdude` already has support for using the RPi SPI headers - just use the `linuxspi` programmer type.

Here's an article by the author that explains it (although there are probably more recent articles if you search around) http://kevincuzner.com/2013/05/27/raspberry-pi-as-an-avr-programmer/

Is there a reason you want to do this from Python specifically? Or are you referring to communicating between the uC firmware and some Python code on the Pi?

Comment: yeah i didnt know i had to program the AVR beforehand, and also with Python, I just wanted to use that to send the signals to the MCU but I have to program the MCU using another language correct?

Comment: Yes, you need to write the AVR code in C (or maybe C++) first, compile that with something like AVR-GCC, which creates a binary, then upload that binary with `avrdude`. Alternatively you could use avrdude to put a bootloader on the AVR and then use something like the Arduino environment to develop your firmware